# SceneManager.LoadScene(string) doesn't recognize scene name

Tags: unity-game-engine, menu

I've seen similar questions all over the internet, but none seem to apply to my situation.

I have a very simple project with two scenes: `MainMenuScene` and `OtherScene`. `OtherScene` is nothing but a blank canvas, and `MainMenuScene` just has a button which is meant to be used to navigate to `OtherScene`. The Main Camera has the following script attached to it:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LaunchScene : MonoBehaviour {

    public void LaunchSceneOnButtonClick(int index)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(index);
    }

    public void LaunchSceneOnButtonClick(string sceneName)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
    }
}
```

and in the `OnClick()` of the button, this script is called. I have made sure to add both levels to the Build Settings.

If I call the version of the `LanchSceneOnButtonClick` which takes an integer argument (and specify the appropriate value in the `OnClick()` method) then the desired scene loads.

*However*, if I call the version which takes a string argument and use the exact name of the scene I want to load (and I've quadruple checked that it is indeed the exact string, that the string name has no spaces or hidden characters, and have copy pasted the scene name into the `OnClick()` argument field) the scene does not load and instead I get the error message

> Scene "OtherScene" couldn't be loaded because it has not been added to
>   the build settings or the AssetBundle has not been loaded.

Since using the scene index works, we know it was added to the Build Settings properly, so I reason that there is some issue with the scene name. But I've copied it exactly. I want to avoid using the full path of the scene in case I later decide to move scenes around to different folders, so what are my options here?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:

Adding screenshots.

Scene in folder structure:

[image]

Scenes in build settings:

[image]

`OnClick()` input:

[image]

[image]

Keep in mind I've also tried the input to `OnClick()` with and without quotation marks.

Comment: This looks more like a bad Spelling. 1.Post the screenshot of the placed you added the scene. 2.Post the screenshot of the folder you placed the scenes. 3.Finally show the string you are passing to that function to let us know that you didn't get the spellings wrong.

Comment: Hi @Programmer. As I said in the post, I copy pasted the name from the Scene name, as well as quadruple checked. I tried with and without quotes as well. Screenshots are included above. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only possible problems are these:

- The string passed is different from the scene name; bear in mind, the string used in `LoadScene` is **not** case sensitive, i.e. you can use `OtherScene`, `OTHERscene`, etc.
- The scene in the build settings is not active (i.e. with the checkmark on the left disabled).
- The scene isn't present at all in the build settings.

The full path of the scene is irrelevant btw, you can have `OtherScene` inside any dir/subdir in the Assets, and you'll need only the name of the scene. You need the full path of the scene only if you have more than scene with the same name in different paths (and anyway you shouldn't, it's such an obvious terrible practice).

EDIT: You say that you tried even without `"` (as you should do, when entering `string` fields in the inspector you don't need them), what happens if you modify the method body to:

```
public void LaunchSceneOnButtonClick(string sceneName)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("OtherScene");
}
```

Try this and report back what happens please.

Comment: Thanks @galandil. I just wanted to reiterate that possibilities 2 and 3 listed above can't actually apply to this case as the scene loads when I use the index (integer argument) version of the function. In terms of possibility 1, please see my update to the post with screen shots. I'm led to believe there is in fact an other possibility that we aren't aware of. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Galandil. I meant to put screenshots for both but had only put one. Now both are included. I tried your suggestion and it worked, which baffled me (since the default input I'm using is without quotes, so it should work), then changed the code back without changing the input and it is now working. How is this possible!?!?

Comment: This is indeed weird. It seems like some kind of weird serialization persistence bug, which went away when you forced the recompile while testing with the string as a parameter. I've had my fair share of weird behaviours in Unity, anytime these happens I always switch scene back and forth (load another scene and then reload the original one) as a first solution, before chasing bugs in my code that don't really exist. :D

Comment: Okay, that is weird, but fortunately it seems to be something easy to work around. I had this same issue in another of my projects but at that time resolved to just call scenes by index. I'll go back and try this approach to get it working. If I were less lazy I'd make a minimum working example for the Unity devs. Thanks for the help here!

Comment: However, that's why I never use the inspector's `OnClick` events in my work, I always add events via `onClick.AddListener` directly in my code. Sometimes the inspector ones just bug out for no reasons at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had also the problem that

```
public void loadScene(string scene)
{
        SceneManager.LoadScene(scene);
}
```

did not work for me in the first place. What did I do? I'm saving the names of my scenes in a List (read from a file) and from that List I choose the scene I need.

But somehow the reading progress seems to give me some unwanted characters so the scene loading does not work as intended. When I added .Trim() it started to work.

For a better understanding, here's an example:

```
string s = sceneList[1].Trim();

this.loadScene(s);

public void loadScene(string scene)
{
        SceneManager.LoadScene(scene);
}
```

So make sure that you get rid of unwanted characters.