# SceneManager.LoadScene not loading scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Buttons : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void loadLevel()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Level");
    }
}
```

This is the code I am using, loadLevel() is supposed to load the scene Level when a button is clicked, this should be simple and I am not sure what is going wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the value of onClick?

Comment: What do your build settings look like? Do you have the scene added there?

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint on that line and attach the debugger to see if it was getting invoked?

Comment: Thanks @NoahBrinton, It's working now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SceneManager.LoadScene(string) doesn't recognize scene name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838271/scenemanager-loadscenestring-doesnt-recognize-scene-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you haven't added the scene "Level" in Build Settings (menu "File"-"Build Settings"). If it isn't in the build it can't be opened by LoadScene.

[image]

To add a scene you can either open it in the editor and then click on the "Add Open Scenes" button, or you can simply drag-and-drop the scene file from the Project-window to the "Scenes In Build".